# Page jumps to the top when checkbox is clicked

Tags: filter, datatables, mootools

I'm calling handleNotableTypeSelect method on the click of the check box, everything is working fine but the page jumps to the top.

```js
this.$hideInactiveCheckbox.click(
    this.handleNotableTypeSelect.createDelegate(this));
    handleNotableTypeSelect: function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        if (this.$hideInactiveCheckbox.attr('checked')) {
            this.isActive = "^active$";     
            this.$connTable.fnFilter(this.isActive, 1,true);     
        }
        else {
            this.$connTable.fnFilter('', 1);
        } 
        //return false;
    }
```

Comment: Edit a bit better that code! puts line breaks check the faq! that's too messy

Comment: Why is there even an `else` there?

Comment: Can u show us an example page? A [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)? Maybe there's more javascript code affecting click's behavior...

Comment: @Purmou `else` is at the same level as the `if`, just marked strangely

Comment: pls ignore previous link, http://jsfiddle.net/EHeEu/2/

Answer (score 23):

My case was that the checkbox was hidden (due to CSS design). the original input checkbox had position set to 'absolute' so when the user clicked the checkbox the page "jumped" to the real checkbox position.

**EDIT:**

In some cases there are styled "fake" checkboxes. the real checkbox element is hidden in some bad practice way.
My case was that the real checkbox element had absolute positioning and hidden and that cause the page jump to top of the window.

**Possible solution:**

Check if the checkbox element has the following CSS rule
`position: absolute;`
if yes, removing this rule can fix this issue.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: i had similar issue. checking a checkbox made the page "jump" to the top. The solution made by modifying CSS rules. so this is a possible solution my friend.

Comment: Just ran into this issue and a hidden checkbox input was the cause. This is definitely something to consider, even if it may not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: But what was the solution here?

Comment: Updated with a solution @Daniel

Comment: removing position:absolute worked for me

Answer (score 12):

This may related to the following issue:

[input checkbox in div jumps to top of page on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562840/input-checkbox-in-div-jumps-to-top-of-page-on-firefox)

I've actually been seeing errors about this in all kinds of frameworks, and for the most part, people post framework specific answers.  If you're hiding the check box, try using display: none on it, it seemed to work for the post above.  I'm still trying to hunt down a fix (since I'm not hiding my checkboxes, I'm trying figure out why checkboxes in a modal cause the screen to jump to the top of the modal on click).

Comment: display: none did the trick. I was hiding the checkboxes at -999px, -999px with a label on the screen. When I clicked on one, unlike radio buttons, the screen tried to scroll to display the checkbox that was selected.
I originally avoided display: none because that used to disable the checkbox. This is no longer the case and may have been an IE6 thing.
If display: none interferes with the page's operation, you might try position: relative; left: -999px so that it does not scroll vertically in its attempts to display it.

Comment: I'm having this issue on an extension.  It's not the checkbox that's hidden for me though.  The checkbox triggers a click that enables or disables a textbox.  When the textbox enables or disables, Firefox jumps to the top of the page.  I have no idea why or how this is happening and I've tried a dozen workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Several frameworks and css tricks hide the checkbox using `position: absolute`.
That is correct because we need to hide the checkbox only from screen, while Screen Readers must have access to it in order to announce it correctly. But `display:none` hides it from them too and users with accessibility issues can't click it.
The most suitable solution is to add `position:relative` to checkbox container and adjust checkbox position using `top:` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

If the checkbox has been positioned absolute to hide it and the interaction occurs on the label (which is commonplace when styling checkboxes beyond the default UI), the page will scroll to wherever the checkbox input is positioned despite the click event occurring on the label. so if you've added `top:-9999px;` for example, the page will jump right up to where it's now positioned.
What you want instead, is to remove it from the rendered layout without moving it away from the label. to do this, add a container div to the label and input, and add `position:relative;` to it. Then add the following code to the input itself:

```
position:absolute;
top:0; left:0;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your check box has `position: absolute`, in most cases just wrapping it (input and label elements) with a div should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have two elements with the same ID. When checkbox label was clicked you jump to the first position.