# input checkbox in div jumps to top of page on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I use `div` over `label` and `input type="checkbox"`. I do this in order to have the checkbox look like a button.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Je87Q/

What should I do with a checkbox or label/input that will stop jumping to the top of my page?

This happens ONLY on Firefox. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Happens in Chrome for me. Post your HTML and CSS here please.

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 22):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/FHWP2/)

Just need a minor CSS change

```
#modbutton label input {
    /* position:absolute; */
    /* top:-20px; */
    display:none; /* ADD */
}
```

Comment: @kei Thanks! It worked like a charm. It would be great if you can add a little explanation or point us in the right direction?

Comment: Setting a checkbox to `display: none` removes the ability to tab on it. [j08691's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21563077/4068027) does not have this problem.

Answer (score 9):

This is happening because you are positioning the checkbox absolutely and -20px above the viewport. When you click on the span, you're triggering the label to change the checkbox which causes the jump to the top. There are a variety of ways to fix this, but an easy one would be to change:

```
#modbutton label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
```

to something like:

```
#modbutton label input {
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Je87Q/3/)**

Answer (score 5):

I got your point

Please change this code for your input field

```
<input id="status" type="checkbox" name="displaystaffstatus" style="position: relative;">
```

or do this thing

```
#modbutton label input {
    display:none;
}
```